# JSDoc Mark something as Class after instantiation and define constructor properties

Tags: javascript, types, jsdoc

I have mongoose create a Model(class) for me, and I would like to have the class to have intellisense. The problem is I don't know how to mark something as a class, and how to type the constructor for that class.

Looking at JSDocs' docs they only specify how to type a class at the declaration, not when it already has been instantiated. The `@class` and `@constructor` tags don't seem to do anything.

Right now I am getting my intellisense by marking it as a function (which it is under the hood, but it would still be great to have the correct colors in VSC) and defining the params:

```js
/**
 * @typedef QPE_Opts
 * @type {object}
 * @prop {string} id - Id of the user 
 * ...
 */
/**
 * @type {function(QPE_Opts) : mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document, {}> }}
 */
const Queue_PoolEntry = mongoose.model('Queue_PoolEntry', Queue_PoolEntrySchema);
```

### Solution

The solution (Was looking at the JsDocs' Documentation which was not providing enough info, thanks @Graham P Heath for giving [the better docs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System)) :

```js
/**
 * @type {function(new:mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document, {}>, QPE_Opts ) }}
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure of the type of an object you can [type cast](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System#type-casts) it:

```
const Queue_PoolEntry = /** @type {QPE_Opts} */ (mongoose.model('Queue_PoolEntry', 
    Queue_PoolEntrySchema));
```

In situations where you can't actually be sure of the returned type casting may be a code smell. In that case: use code to determine the validity of your type assertion by checking the object for expected properties, and only then casting it.

```
let Queue_PoolEntry = mongoose.model('Queue_PoolEntry', 
    Queue_PoolEntrySchema);
if (Queue_PoolEntry && Queue_PoolEntry.id) {
  Queue_PoolEntry = /** @type {QPE_Opts} */ (Queue_PoolEntry)
} else {
  throw new Error('mongoose.model(\'Queue_PoolEntry\', Queue_PoolEntrySchema)'+
      'returned something other than a QPE_Opts' + Queue_PoolEntry);
}
```

Comment: `>The problem is I don't know how to mark something as a class, and how to type the constructor for that class.`

mongoose.model always returns a class. I don't know **how to type a class** without having access to the class declaration. I want to **typecast to a class** and type its **constructor**. Currently I am faking that by typecasting it to a **function** which has problems like the **new keyword** not working etc. My question is **not how to typecast** but **how to declare a custom type that is a class with a typed constructor**

Comment: To mark anything as another type, you can typecast it. To create a type, your type def looks ok to me, but if its not read the docs: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System You want to type something as a class and doing so will change the attributes of its constructor. Finally, `@class` and `@constructor` predate ES6 and have no place in ES6 classes and constructors.

Comment: The docs made it work, had to use the `function(new:...)`

Answer (score 0):

Shorten version will work as well

```
/**
 * @type {new(arg: QPE_Opts) => mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document, {}>}
 */
```